# Ken Burns effect using Joelambert's Flux Slider? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, effect

I am currently using Joelambert's Flux Slider.

GitHub: https://github.com/joelambert/Flux-Slider

Demo: http://www.joelambert.co.uk/flux/

Basically there are many effects such as Bar, Slide, Swipe. Each of these effects is implemented in its respective function. For instance, the codes for the effect for dissolve (fading) is shown below.

I wish to create the **Ken Burns effect** using this API, is it possible?

An example of the **Ken Burns effect** is seen in the link provided (wowslider.com/jquery-slider-bar-kenburns-demo.html). It is a type of zooming and panning effect of an image in a frame.

**What I have tried**: adding in `'-webkit-transform':'rotate(7deg)'` under the setup() or execute() function, but the rotation only appears when it transits into the next image.

Would like the images displayed to animate, basically having zooming, rotation and panning. Any guidance is deeply appreciated.

Thank you, Radiance.

```
(function($) {
    flux.transitions.dissolve = function(fluxslider, opts) {
        return new flux.transition(fluxslider, $.extend({
            setup: function() {
                var img = $('<div class="image"></div>').css({
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    'opacity':'1',
                    'filter':'alpha(opacity=100)',
                    'zoom':'1',
                    '-webkit-backface-visibility': 'hidden',
                    'background-image': this.slider.image1.css('background-image')  
                }).css3({
                    'transition-duration': '600ms',
                    'transition-timing-function': 'ease-in',
                    'transition-property': 'opacity'
                });

                this.slider.image1.append(img);
            },
            execute: function() {
                var _this = this,
                    img = this.slider.image1.find('div.image');

                // Get notified when the last transition has completed
                $(img).transitionEnd(function(){
                    _this.finished();
                });

                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(img).css({
                        'opacity': '0.0'
                    });
                }, 50);
            }
        }, opts));
    };
})(window.jQuery || window.Zepto);
```

Comment: What is the "Ken Burns effect"?

Comment: Ken Burns Effect demonstration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNTiyRDhlRY

Comment: The effect is seen in the link provided. It is a type of zooming and panning effect of an image in a frame. http://wowslider.com/jquery-slider-bar-kenburns-demo.html

Comment: Your question cannot depend on external links to be answerable, that renders your question off-topic for this site.